# Redireccionar pagina al clickar imagen

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando crear una pagina web y me estoy encontrando con algún problema.

Mediante classes de [php](/questions/tagged/php) he mostrado una imagen y un texto en la pagina principal, ahora necesito que al pinchar en la foto me lleve a otra pagina donde mostrar la información pero no se como hacerlo para no tener que crear una pagina diferente en cada imagen.

```
<section class="cap_anadido">
        <div> <?php foreach ($series as $serie ) { ?>
            <figure>
                <div class="imagen">
                    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $serie['imagen'] ?>" title="" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3><a href="#"><?php echo $serie['nombre'] ?></a></h3>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="reset"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Así pinto la imagen y el texto, luego tengo otro archivo html donde quiero pintar la información.
No he hecho nada mas porque no se por donde empezar a hacer la redirección

Comment: Hola Hailey,  puedes editar la pregunta para añadir el codigo html y php actual, asi como lo que has probado para redireccionar? asi sobre ese codigo podemos decirte que tienes mal o como mejorarlo ^^ Un saludo

Comment: Podrias guardar las variables de la imagen en `$_SESSION` y pasarlas a un html donde pongas la información por medio de las variables. No me queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer, pero si es pasar información de una pagina a otra esta es una solución.

Comment: lo que intento hacer es una pagina para ver series, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pincho en la imagen o cuando me salen los resultados por el buscador me vaya a esa pagina donde aparece la información de esa serie

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pasar por parámetro en la URL el id de la serie de cada imagen, por ejemplo

```
www.mipaginaweb.com/info.php?id_serie=1
```

Y luego recoger ese valor por $_REQUEST['id_serie'] y enlazarlo a tu query de BBDD. Si lo pones en tu bucle cada enlace tendría un id de serie distinto e iría a una página diferente sin crear un archivo por cada serie, solo te hace falta un parámetro para cambiar de información, y te quedaría así:

```
<section class="cap_anadido">
        <div> <?php foreach ($series as $serie ) { ?>
            <figure>
                <div class="imagen">
                    <a href="info.php?id_serie=<?php echo $serie['id']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $serie['imagen'] ?>" title="" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <figcaption>
                    <h3><a href="info.php?id_serie=<?php echo $serie['id']; ?><?php echo $serie['nombre'] ?></a></h3>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="reset"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que redireccionar si puedes ocupar un modal?

Para hacer esto, ya que estaremos por el lado del cliente simplemente, deberemos ocupar `javascript` o `jquery`, y por sentido práctico que da la herramienta `bootstrap`.

```js
//Javascript
function abrirModal(objeto, detalleImg){
  $(".modal-body").html($(objeto).html() + "<br> " + $("."+detalleImg).html());
}
```

```css
/*CSS*/
p{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>Ejemplo</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Ejemplo Modal</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" onclick="abrirModal(this, 'detalleImg1')">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_html5_html5.gif">
      <p class="detalleImg1">Este es el detalle de HTML5</p>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" onclick="abrirModal(this, 'detalleImg2')">
      <img src="https://d21ii91i3y6o6h.cloudfront.net/gallery_images/from_proof/2236/large/1413860642/javascript.png">
      <p class="detalleImg2">Este es el detalle de Javascript</p>
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Detalle Imagen</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
 </body>
</html>
```

Hay varias formas de jugar con javascript o jquery por el lado del cliente.

Te dejo las referencias para que puedas estudiarlas si gustas

[Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) - [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

**NOTA:**

Puedes hacer llamada `ajax` si necesitas que la imagen traiga mas información de forma asincrona, vale decir, que pinches, esta cargue y devuelva el resultado sin necesidad de que salgas de la pagina.

Dejo documentación de ello si necesitas

[Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) - [Ajax-Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)